# Creating a Static IP With wlan0

Tags: static-ip, wlan

I am trying to figure out how to create a static IP address for my Ubuntu server. So far, I have scoured the internet and have only found how to do it with eth0, when I am using a PCI adapter for my main send/receive. This may not be as efficient as Ethernet, but this is simply for learning web structure, if you will.

Is there a difference between setup for wlan0 and eth0 static IP? If not, can I be referred to a site that explains how to do this in the fullest manner?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is yes, do it the same way. By the time wlan0 is working (which is generally the tricky part in Linux), it is being treated the same as eth0 and you can use identical directives to configure wlan0 however you wish.

EDIT: Instructions

Open /etc/network/interfaces using your favorite text editor (I use vim):

```
vim /etc/networking/interfaces
```

It will look something like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

Make it look like this instead (using your own values for `address`, `netmask`, etc):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Bring down the interface (simplest way to release DHCP IP):

```
ifdown wlan0
```

Bring it back up (simplest way to effect new setting):

```
ifup wlan0
```

Comment: Okay, but this does not explain how I should set it up...

Answer (score 2):

Although, static ip for LAN is straight forward, I found trouble finding instructions for static ip for wifi
Following works on Debian 10 (Year 2020), even in text only mode, or with ssh-ed system

- connect with LAN
- connect internet
- `apt install network-manager` (this will install nmtui)
- `nmtui`
- set static ip for your wifi, save, exit, restart

Answer (score 1):

Here is a decent write up.

It's pretty likely you don't need the ndiswrapper part of this. That is only useful if you need to pull the windows drivers to make your nic work.

http://modelr.wordpress.com/2009/06/01/how-to-get-wireless-network-on-ubuntu-server/

Comment: Very decent indeed.

Comment: But what is this used for? It does not set a static ip

Comment: I just tried this and it made matters worse.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following steps to set a static ip in Ubuntu :

`/etc/network/interfaces` configuration file. You need to open this file using a text editor such as vi or gedit.

Open terminal, and type the following command:

```
% sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

OR

```
% sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Make the changes as follows:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.10.29.66
netmask 255.255.255.192
network 10.10.29.65
broadcast 10.10.29.127
gateway 10.10.29.65
```

Save and close the file. Restart networking:

```
% sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Yes, a little difference between Wlan0 and eth0. Use [this link to learn more details about wlan0 and eth0](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=2287).

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me in Ubuntu 22.10:

```bash
cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

```yaml
network:
    version: 2
    wifis:
        renderer: networkd
        wlan0:
            access-points:
                MY_AP:
                    password: 12345678
            # Static IP address I want to set
            addresses:
                - 192.168.1.2/24
             # Google and Cloudflare DNS
            nameservers:
              addresses: [4.2.2.2, 8.8.8.8]
            # default gateway, AKA router
            routes:
              - to: default
                via: 192.168.1.2
```

Then `netplan apply`.